# Increment AI with on duplicate key

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have a sql query with a ON DUPLICATE KEY condition.

```
INSERT INTO users (username) VALUES (username) ON DUPLICATE KEY update ics = ics +1;
```

My table looks like

TABLE: users
FIELD: userID, username, ics with userID have an AI.

Where I insert an user, the AI count increase and when the ON DUPLICATE KEY work, the AI count increase too.

I whish when an user exist, only the ics field update. Not the AI count.

What is wrong.

My problem is when I have a duplicate key, the next id is higher.

Thanks for ur help.

Comment: Why do you care about values of an artificial integer index? They can be completely random without any change in logic.

Comment: Did you make sure `username` has a unique index?

Comment: The problem is, actually the last AI is 198745844 too much.. I use this query in a script and he is working until 2 weeks. And I want to increase ics where the username is find, and add him where he isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming usernames are indeed unique, you need to make sure there is a `UNIQUE INDEX` defined on the column `username`.  If not, you'll get the problem you're having.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX id_index ON users (username);
```

Otherwise, your `INSERT ... UPDATE` is fine for achieving your desired result.